# Do you see any error? Not pulling the correct data

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull data from the following SUBSTR however its not giving me the correct total. Thanks in advance!

```
SUM
(
    CASE
        WHEN l16lcode IN ('4')
            AND l16movef IN ('7') 
            AND SUBSTR(routeno, 1,4) IN ('LSEA','LAFUL','LTEM','LVAN','LOSD','LBFR','LAVE')
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic you want to implement, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Within the desired substrings, there's one with length 5 (LAFUL). Looks like an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder guys and i apologize as I am still a newbie here. Anyway the desired output is for this to Sum up all data that has the name of those inside the SUBSTR. Since we have some names LSEA11, LSEA12 etc. If I add all the names manually I would get the correct amount.

Comment: @Nixon: are you sure the substring `LAFUL` is correct?

Comment: @RobertKock, yes that is correct we have quite a few LAFUL, LAFUL1, LAFUL2,LAFUL3

Comment: The function `SUBSTR(routeno, 1,4)` will never match `LAFUL` so you'll miss all elements whose routeno starts with LAFUL

Comment: @RobertKock, hi again. Is there another way where I can sum up the total that has the letters of each SUBSTR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that the only problem is caused by the fact that there are `routeno` values with a prefix of 5 characters, you might try the following:

```
SUM
(
  CASE
    WHEN l16lcode IN ('4')
      AND l16movef IN ('7') 
      AND (SUBSTR(routeno, 1,4) IN ('LSEA','LTEM','LVAN','LOSD','LBFR','LAVE') OR
           SUBSTR(routeno, 1,5) IN ('LAFUL')
          )
    THEN 1 ELSE 0
  END
)
```

Comment: I tried this and still getting a different result. I went ahead and just deducted the total result from the other total and got the correct results. Thanks for all the help Robert Kock